Dúvida sobre identificação do sujeito numa construção específica
Qual é a oração mais gramaticalmente correta das duas citadas abaixo?

"Tem erros de logística que 10 anos atrás seria inconcebível um gestor cometer."

(Penso que aqui o sujeito é oculto, ato de cometer um erro, e, portando, seria deve concordar com ele, ficando no singular).

"Tem erros de logística que 10 anos atrás seriam inconcebíveis um gestor cometer."

(Aqui o sujeito é erros, portanto deve-se usar seriam).
Quem/o que seria (seriam) inconcebível (inconcebíveis)?
Essa escolha é trivial?

Essa é uma sintaxe bem... bem complicada.

"erros" não é o sujeito de nenhuma das frases.

Embora a resposta com mais votos diga o contrário, o verbo no plural não é correto. Vê a resposta de Artefacto, e para uma análisa sintática completa a minha.

A resposta correta é com o singular, seria e inconcebível.
Há aqui mais do que uma oração. É irrelevante que o verbo ter (aqui =haver, no sentido de de existir), seja impessoal e que portanto vá para a terceira pessoa do singular nessa oração.
Na oração relativa "que seria inconcebível um gestor cometer", que, pronome relativo, assume como antecedente "erros de logística". É verdade que este nome é plural, no entanto, este nome é o objeto direto de cometer, não o sujeito de ser inconcebível. O sujeito de ser inconcebível é um sujeito oracional, a oração infinitiva um gestor cometer [certos erros]. Repara que podemos dizer que certos erros são inconcebíveis, não apenas que cometer certos erros é inconcebível, o que ajuda à confusão. Se a frase errada fosse truncada após "inconcebíveis" ("há erros que, há dez anos, seriam inconcebíveis"), então a frase estaria correta, o que induz ao erro.
A análise mudaria se admitíssemos a elevação a sujeito de "erros de logística" com de, como com o adjetivo "difícil", ou "impossível":

Há problemas que é difícil resolver.
Há problemas que são difíceis de resolver.
Há problemas que é difícil um gestor resolver.
(?) Há problemas que são difíceis de um gestor resolver [problemas].

Marquei com (?) porque não me parece que nesta construção resolver possa ter um sujeito explícito.

Creio que minha e tua resposta estejam em concórdia. Na quarta construção realmente "resolver" não pode ter sujeito, "de um gestor resolver" é oração completiva nominal e o verbo "resolver" é usado de modo geral.

"Sujeito oracional ocorre quando há uma oração subordinada substantiva fazendo papel de sujeito, a chamada oração subjetiva". Ex: Praticar exercícios frequentemente é bom para a saúde. https://www.clubedoportugues.com.br/o-que-e-sujeito-oracional/ Eu não vejo nenhum sujeito oracional.  Tem erros de logística// que 10 anos atrás seriam inconcebíveis// um gestor cometer. Mas:  Um gestor cometer erros de logítstica dez anos atrás seria [singular aqui sim] inconcebível.

@Lambie o que é inconcebível (i.e. o sujeito do predicado ser inconcebível) é um gestor cometer certos erros, não os erros. Logo, segundo este teste, o sujeito é "um gestor cometer certos erros".

Não creio que seja trivial, pois julgo o singular a forma própria. Essa frase tem uma sintaxe bem complicada.
Simplifiquemos a frase, trocando o 'ter' de sentido existencial por um verbo transitivo direto qualquer e removendo a locução adverbial '10 anos atrás' (nada muda no significado, só simplifica a análise sintática por enquanto):

Conheço erros de logística que é/são inconcebível/inconcebíveis um gestor cometer.

A frase pode ser reestruturada para "Conheço erros de logística que um gestor cometer é inconcebível."

Análise sintática:

Oração principal: Conheço erros de logística
Conheço–(verbo) erros de logística–(objeto direto)
Oração subordinada adjetiva restritiva (OSAR): que um gestor cometer é inconcebível.
Oração principal da OSAR: é inconcebível
é-(verbo) inconcebível-(predicativo do sujeito) [o sujeito desta oração é a oração abaixo]
Oração subordinada substantiva subjetiva: um gestor cometer [erros de logística – referido pelo pronome relativo 'que']
um gestor–(sujeito) cometer–(verbo) [erros de logística – referido pelo pronome relativo 'que']-(objeto direto)
Oração subordinada adjetiva restritiva: que–(pronome relativo sujeito) são–(verbo copulativo) inconcebíveis–(predicativo do sujeito)

Restaurando a frase original, teremos:

Tem erros de logística que 10 anos atrás seria inconcebível um gestor cometer.
Tem erros de logística – oração principal
Tem – verbo transitivo direto impessoal
erros de logística – objeto direto
que 10 anos atrás seria inconcebível um gestor cometer – oração subordinada adjetiva restritiva
que – pronome relativo sujeito de "um gestor cometer"
10 anos atrás – adjunto adverbial
seria inconcebível – oração principal da OSAR (o sujeito é a oração abaixo)
um gestor cometer [erros de logística – referido pelo pronome relativo 'que'] – oração subordinada substantiva subjetiva
Todavia, se considerarmos como correto o plural e que de 'são' 'erros' é sujeito , teremos a frase "Conheço erros de logística que são inconcebíveis...", a qual já se encerra completamente e logo admite complemento nenhum. Vide:
Oração principal: Eu-(sujeito) conheço-(verbo) erros de logística-(objeto direito)
Logo, "um gestor cometer" ficaria solto como sintagma se o sujeito do verbo 'ser' fosse 'erros' em vez 'um gestor cometer [erros que conheço].
Um modo de "dessoltar" esse sintagma enquanto se mantém o plural é a introdução da preposição "de":

Conheço erros de logística que são inconcebíveis de um gestor cometer.

Essa frase é do mesmo tipo de "Igrejas são difíceis de plebeus construírem.". "Igreja" é o sujeito, "são" é o verbo, "difíceis" é o predicativo do sujeito, "de plebeus construírem" é o complemento nominal do predicativo do sujeito, sendo uma oração subordinada substantiva completiva nominal reduzida de infinitivo.
Concluindo:
As opções certas podem ser ou "Conheço erros de logística que são inconcebíveis de um gestor cometer", ou "Conheço erros de logística que é inconcebível um gestor cometer" — uma inversão de "Conheço erros de logística que um gestor cometer é inconcebível".
Mas eu diria que existe uma sutílima distinção semântica entre as duas, e que a primeira é mais apropriada, enquanto que a segunda não faz tanto sentido quanto aquela.

Na língua culta a frase correta seria: Há erros de logística que há 10 anos seriam inconcebíveis um gestor cometer.
Oração sem sujeito: verbo haver com o sentido de existir.

Isso foi o que eu disse na minha resposta.

Identificação do sujeito da frase.
O verbo ter como impessoal (tem) ou um verbo com sujeito oculto:
A pergunta vai sobre o sujeito da frase e o termo erros de logística que é complemento.
Os verbos ter e haver se usam em um modo impessoal:

Uso impessoal do verbo ter
Flávia Neves Flávia Neves Professora de Português
Em linguagem informal, o verbo ter pode ser utilizado como
um verbo impessoal, sendo conjugado apenas na 3.ª pessoa do singular.
Isso ocorre quando é usado com o sentido de ter existência, sendo
sinônimo de haver:
Há pessoas na entrada esperando por você. Tem pessoas na entrada
esperando por você.

uso impessoal do verbo ter
Então na frase:
Tem erros de logística que 10 anos atrás seriam inconcebíveis um gestor cometer.
Tem pode se lê como: Há ou tem no sentido de existe, uso do tem como impessoal. Na leitura há como tem, o há funciona como verbo impessoal.
Se tem se lê como ele tem, o sujeito é oculto sim:
Pois bem, ou a frase não tem sujeito (há ou tem), ou tem sujeito oculto: (ele) tem.
Independemente de tudo isso, nenhuma dessas interpretações de "tem" afeta o fato que erros de logística é um complemento do verbo ter, e não o sujeito da frase. E são os erros de logística que seriam inconcebíveis um gestor cometer. A concordância entre erros, o verbo ser e o ajetivo inconcebível agora parece mais óbvia...
Conclusão: erros de logística=sujeito, verbo: seriam, o plural.

Se "erros" concorda com o verbo 'ser', qual é a função sintática de "um gestor cometer"?
O sujeito do verbo 'ter' é completamente irrelevante para a pergunta, que é a concordância do verbo 'ser'.

@Quaestoria Isso não faz parte da pergunta. Ele perguntou: Dúvida sobre identificação do sujeito numa construção específica Ele pensa que o sujeito da frase é erros. Mas não é. E é no caso: os erros de logística que seriam inconcebíveis um gestor cometer. Todo o problema vem desse "desentendimento".

Isso é exatamente a questão da pergunta. "Tem erros de logística que" e "os erros de logística que" não possuem diferença qualquer sobre a classificação sintática dos sintagmas que procedem.

"Dúvida sobre identificação do sujeito numa construção específica" e também diz: "Aqui o sujeito é erros, portanto deve-se usar seriam".  Eis os problemas levantados por ele. Não vale a pena pretender que a pergunta é outra. Tá escrito em negro e branco.

O perguntador também diz "aqui o sujeito é oculto". Ele levanta duas possibilidades, daí a pergunta. O problema é que naquela frase "erros de logística" não é sujeito de oração nenhuma!

@Quaestoria  Eu já falei TUDO ISSO. Lê bem a minha resposta. Credo. Eu disse: erros de logística é um complemento do verbo ter, e não o sujeito da frase. Poderia ficar mais claro?

@Quaestoria Você consideraria válido considerar que, remetendo à opção de adicionar um "de" sugerida na tua resposta, esse "de" poderia estar implícito? Se for uma possibilidade, isso permitiria o plural também.
